# Custom action button for executing intellij plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pycharm, intellij-plugin

I have written a Intellij plugin that defines a custom action. I want to execute this via button icon like below.

[image]

Any pointers on how to add this?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development is the best place for such questions.

Comment: Thanks! Sometime it helps to be not a purist though. I figured out that it can be achieved through <add-to-group group-id="ToolbarRunGroup" anchor="last"/>.

Answer (score 2):

Following worked for me:

```
<action id="MyCustomAction.UniqueID"
        class="com.mycompany.MyCustomAction"
        text="Execute an action" icon="/MyIcons/icon-16x16.png">
    <add-to-group group-id="ToolbarRunGroup" anchor="last"/>
</action>
```

It looks as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the action to the `VcsNavBarToobarActions` groups. You can do this by adding something like the below to your `plugin.xml`.

```xml
<actions>
        <group text="MyNavBarGroup">
            <add-to-group group-id="VcsNavBarToobarActions" anchor="last"/>
            <action class="com.myplugin.action.RandomAction" text="Random" icon="/icons/pdf-icon.png"/>
        </group>
</actions>
```

I added a random pdf icon because that's what I had on hand.
[image]

See the discussion on
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004225719-New-actions-on-toolbar

Comment: Thanks! Adding to ToolbarRunGroup was a better solution in my case.

Comment: No worries, could I please ask you to confirm and upvote the answer if you're happy with it? Let me know if you have any other questions about plugin development in the future, I may be able to help out.